# Do I need a comma after "given that" and "in absence of"?

Tags: commas

**Example sentences**

- Given that the survey is representative(,) the author still assumes that the 450 respondents are the majority of those surveyed.
- In absence of this information(,) the author's conclusion is logically unpersuasive.

**Questions**

1. Do I need to write a comma where I show "(,)" in these sentences above?
2. Could you also tell me if there is a reason that can be generalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, a comma is appropriate.

The first part of each sentence, before the comma, is a dependent clause because it contains a noun and a verb, but does not express a complete thought. The part after the comma is a main clause because it has a subject and verb and expresses a complete thought.

From the [Purdue University Online Writing Lab](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html)

> Use commas after introductory a) clauses, b) phrases, or c) words that come before the main clause.